# In Django, form isn't rendered on browser

Tags: python, django

I have started learning django, but I can't understand how to render form.

This is form.py I have made.

```
from django import forms

class TweetForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea(attrs = {'rows' : 1, 'cols' : 85}), max_length = 160)
    country = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())
```

This is code snippet in views.py.

```
from .forms import TweetForm
class Profile(View):
    def get(self, request, username):
        params = dict()
        user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(user = user)
        params["user"] = user
        params["tweets"] = tweets
        form = TweetForm
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'params' : params, 'form' : form})
```

This is html file and it must render form I have made.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <form method="post" action="post/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fieldWrapper">
                    {{ form.text.errors }}
                    {{ form.text }}
                </div>
                {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="post">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            {% for tweet in tweets %}
                <div class="well">
                    <span>{{ tweet.text }}</span>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I issue command(run server), browser don't render form without any exception.
I think there is a problem in views.py file, But I can't find it.
How can I send form parameter to Template(.html file) and render form in result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't instantiate the form.
You need to instantiate the form, for rendering in a template, like this,

```
form = TweetForm()
```

Note:

The `params` variable is already a dict(), you could just add form into the params like this,

```
params['form'] = form
```

Then, render the template with context as params,

```
render(request, 'profile.html', params)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed params but nothing has happened. In template(profile.html), how can I use params? Is it right  **{{ form.text }}**.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You need to change in your view, where form is defined, `form=TweetForm()`, instantiate the form.

Comment: Thanks. form has appeared. but css isn't I have intended.

Comment: You can read more about changing the css classes in form widget attributes here from the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/